# if statement (element.click or break) not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of `<li>` tags and I need to click on the one that contains the certain number (let's say 4).

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
```

and my code is:

```
int a = 4;
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li")); 
    for (WebElement element: allElements) {
        String bText = element.getText();
        int b = Integer.parseInt(bText);
        System.out.println(a + " ? " + b);
        if (a == b){
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

The Eclipse result is:

```
1 ? 4
2 ? 4
3 ? 4
4 ? 4
5 ? 4
```

I don't get it what's wrong with the `if` statement (as the `element.click();` or `break;` not working)... can anyone help please?

Comment: Is that actual eclipse output or one you put together yourself as an example of the output you are see?  I only ask, because I can't see anything wrong with the if state.  You could give each item and id and use getElement with an id rather than xpath.

Comment: That's the output of Eclipse (and the real code... I only modify the class names, but that's not important here as long as the Eclipse print out the correct numbers). I cannot modify the website, it is on www.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change your xpath expression by

```
"//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li[text()='4']"
```

To get the li tag with the value you want

Comment: @Shubham Jain
I modify the code like:
'code'String xpathText = "\"//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li[text()='" + a + "']\"";
System.out.println(xpathText);
WebElement number1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathText));
number1.click();'code'
The error is (xpathText is printed out correctly):
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector "//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li[text()='4']" is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:-

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li[4]")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Actually the control is not going inside if loop, 

    use below approch

    String a = "4";
    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li")); 
        for (WebElement element: allElements) {
            String bText = element.getText();
            System.out.println(a + " ? " + bText );
            if (a.equals(bText)){
                element.click();
                break;
            }
        }



OR

Use javascript click instead of normal click....................... 

    String a = "4";
    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li"));`enter code here`
for(int i=0; i<allElements.size;i++)
{
if(a.equals(allElements.get(i).gettext(bText))
{
javascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", allElements.get(i));
}   
}
```

Comment: The code works, I printed out the values inside if loop and the break do his job perfectly, but I still have the problem with the element.click(), because doesn't click the right number, but that's not the case here. I will look deeper to the website code to understand why doesn't work properly, as the element found with this code should be the right one.
Thank you very much guyz for the help, highly appreciate it!

Comment: Use javascript click instead of normal click....................... 
for(int i=0; i<allElements.size;i++)
{
if(a.equals(allElements.get(i).gettext(bText))
{
javascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", allElements.get(i));
}  
}

Answer (score 0):

@Manjunatha.N
I don't know exactly why the control doesn't go inside the `if` statement, but I manage to make it work:

```
int a = 4;
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='divClass']/ul[@class='ulClass']/li")); 
    for (WebElement element: allElements) {
        String bText = element.getText();
        int b = Integer.parseInt(bText);
        if (a != b) {
            System.out.println(a + " = " + b + "? are not equal!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(a + " = " + b + "? are equal!");
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

And the Eclipse output is now:

```
1 = 4? are not equal!
2 = 4? are not equal!
3 = 4? are not equal!
4 = 4? are equal!
```

And click on the desired element!!!!